# R read excel file from a download link with R

Tags: r, excel, web

I want to read the excel file from this [Link](https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/geratabela?format=xlsx&name=tabela6402.xlsx&terr=N&rank=-&query=t/6402/n1/all/n2/all/v/4104/p/all/c86/all/d/v4104%201/l/v,p,t%2Bc86), it is table from Brazilian Institut of Statistics. How can I do that? I've tried this:

tab <- "https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/geratabela?format=xlsx&name=tabela6402.xlsx&terr=N&rank=-&query=t/6402/n1/all/n2/all/v/4104/p/all/c86/all/d/v4104%201/l/v,p,t%2Bc86"

library(readxl)

df <- read_excel(tab)

Answer (score 4):

Give this modified version a try.

```
library(RCurl)
library(readxl)

temp.file <- paste(tempfile(),".xlsx",sep = "")
download.file("https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/geratabela?format=xlsx&name=tabela6402.xlsx&terr=N&rank=-&query=t/6402/n1/all/n2/all/v/4104/p/all/c86/all/d/v4104%201/l/v,p,t%2Bc86", temp.file, mode = "wb")

tmp <- read_excel(temp.file, skip = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just saving file in local works:

```
library(RCurl)
download.file("https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/geratabela?format=xlsx&name=tabela6402.xlsx&terr=N&rank=-&query=t/6402/n1/all/n2/all/v/4104/p/all/c86/all/d/v4104%201/l/v,p,t%2Bc86", "temp.xlsx")
libary(readxl)
tmp <- read_excel("temp.xlsx", skip = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, but look what happened:

> tmp <- read_excel("temp.xlsx", skip = 2)

Error in read_xlsx_(path, sheet, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types,  : 
  error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo